# One hot encoding in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm trying to learn machine learning.

I had a doubt about one hot encoding:
I have a data set split into 2 excel sheets of data. One sheet has train and other has test data. I first trained my model by importing the train data sheet with pandas. There are categorical features in the data set that have to be encoded. I one hot encoded them.

After importing the test dataset , if I one hot encode it, will the encoding be the same as of the train data set or will it be different. If so, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: How did you perfrom one-hot encoding.? Manually or by using sklearn.?

Comment: If your train/test sets contain different values in the categorical that you are one hot encoding, then you will get different columns returned. IMO, your options are to either encode train/test together, or write a function to add the appropriate dummy columns to your one hot encoded train/test sets.

Answer (score 1):

OneHot Encoding creates binary attribute per category or per value, one attribute equal to 1 ( and o otherwise). One Attribute equal to 1 (hot), while the others will be 0 (cold).

sample example:-

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
1hot = encoder.fit_transform(df_object.reshape(-1,1))
1hot
```

sample output:-

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

you need to check if an attribute which you are fitting in oneHotEncoding are relatively closeby values or not.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 seperate sheets ( for test and train data set). you have to one-hot encode both the sheets seperately after importing it into the pandas data frame.

and **YES one hot encoding will be the same** for the same data set no matter you apply on different data sheets, make sure you have same categorical values in that column in each of your data sheet